# Trouble finishing transaction in Google digital wallet

Tags: android-pay

Trouble finishing transaction in Google digital wallet.
I recieve the first screen from Google wallet.
When I press "Buy" on this screen.
I then get 
"
 Uh oh. There was a problem.
We couldn't complete your purchase because of a technical issue.

Details of the problem below:

Unfortunately, we could not confirm your purchase with the merchant's server. Your order has been canceled. Please contact the merchant if this problem continues.
130110 11:54:15-0500 F5HORI"

I have a posturl set up in my account, and the url is implemented on my server(i've used your java example) according to my server logs and diagnostics, the postback url is not getting called.

There is no auth on my server, the postback is running on port 8080.

Comment: Check that you provided the correct URL _and_ port (I haven't personally tried using a port number in callback url) in the _appropriate_ account (sandbox vs. production).

Comment: Thanks,
These have been verified.